# RSpec controller testing with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip, rspec-rails

So with rails 4.2.0 and the latest rspec I generated a basic test for my controller. I'm just stuck with how to test a paperclip image in the valid_attributes.

From searching around so far I've come up with this (which doesn't work):

```
let(:valid_attributes) {{name: 'The New Room', description: 'This is the brand new room', size: '250', capacity: '100', price: '650', picture: '#{rails.root}/spec/support/room-controller-valid.jpg', rmcat_id: '1'}}
```

Is there another way to do this? Or do I need to include a helper to get paperclip to work with RSpec?

The error I'm getting in terminal is:

`Failure/Error: room = Room.create! valid_attributes
 Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError:
 No handler found for "\#{rails.root}/spec/support/room-controller-valid.jpg`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the Paperclip metadata attributes, instead of providing a real `:picture` attachment.

```
...
picture_file_name: 'room-controller-valid.jpg',
...
```

If you are validating attachment content type or size, set those attributes as well:

```
...
picture_file_name: 'room-controller-valid.jpg',
picture_content_type: 'image/jpeg',
picture_file_size: 1.megabyte,
...
```

Of course, this won't pass your file to the controller, so you don't need the file in order to accomplish this. But your model instance should pass validation. From the Paperclip [README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage):

> Paperclip will wrap up to four attributes (all prefixed with that attachment's 
>   name, so you can have multiple attachments per model if you wish) and give them a 
>   friendly front end. These attributes are:
>
> ```
> <attachment>_file_name
> <attachment>_file_size
> <attachment>_content_type
> <attachment>_updated_at
> ```
>
> By default, only _file_name is required for paperclip to operate. 
>   You'll need to add _content_type in case you want to use content type 
>   validation.